# SQL logic error: near "RETURNING": syntax error (1) Go and SQLite

Tags: sql, go

I'm creating a crud application and I'm testing the database with an in-memory DB.
The only test and functions that are breaking are the toggleTask func and test.

function:

```
func (r *Repository) ToggleTask(task Task) (Task, error) {
    query := "UPDATE Tasks SET completed = NOT completed WHERE id = (?)"
    _, err := r.db.Exec(query, task.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return task, err
    }

    query = "SELECT id, txt, completed FROM Tasks WHERE id = (?) RETURNING *"
    err = r.db.QueryRow(query, task.ID).Scan(&task.ID, &task.Text, &task.ListID, &task.Completed)
    if err != nil {
        return task, err
    }

    return task, nil
}
```

test:

```
const (
    ToggleTask = "SELECT id, txt, completed FROM Tasks WHERE id = (?) RETURNING *"
)

func TestToggleTask(t *testing.T) {
    repo := mockDbRepo()
    list := List{Name: "Test List"}
    repo.db.Exec(CreateList, list.Name)

    task := Task{Text: "Test Task", ListID: list.ID}
    repo.db.Exec(CreateTask, task.Text, task.ListID)

    completedTask,err := repo.ToggleTask(task)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(completedTask, task) {
        t.Errorf("Expected %v, got %v", task, completedTask)
    }
}
```

The test returns to me:

> SQL logic error: near "RETURNING": syntax error (1)

Comment: It does not make sense to use RETURNING in a SELECT statement and SQLite does not support it. Remove RETURNING and everything after that from your statements.

Comment: If I don’t use a returning how can I scan the results from the select query. Now I’m getting  
“sql:no rows in result set”

Comment: A SELECT statement is by design returning rows. I can't say if your go code is correct, but if it is, then it is possible there are no rows in the table with that id.

Comment: Yeah thank you a lot it’s now working. I have an issue with vsCode and its not saving and compiling at moments and I need to restart it several times to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is incorrect. As stated in the SQL Lite docs, `SELECT` does not accept a `RETURNING` clause. The `SELECT` clause by itself returns data.
Remove your `RETURNING` clauses in your queries and you should be good.

SQL Lite Ref: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html